# Python: Print Specific line of text out of TD tag

Tags: python, parsing, iteration, beautifulsoup

This is an easy one I am sure. I am parsing a website and I am trying to get the specific text in between  tags. The text will either == [revoked, Active, Default]  I am using Python. I have been able to print out all the inner text results, but I have not been able to find a good solution on the web for specific text. Here is my code

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url = urllib2.urlopen("Some URL")
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for tag in soup.findAll(re.compile("^a")):

print(tag.text)
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. What do you want to get?

Comment: @kirelagin I am trying to get specific text that is between <a href> tags. The text will either be "Revoked", "Active", or "Default". I hope that clears it up, if ot I am not sure how to rephrase

Comment: What's wrong with using `tag.text`?

Comment: @kirelagin The problem is that I want "specific" instances not all the instances. I should report that I am a beginner python user, and all of my code as been compiled from multiple tutorials and web references

Comment: The problem is not your code, but you not being clear about what you want to do.

Comment: @kirelagin Okay, I only want to PRINT specific results is that better? I am trying to work with you on phrasing my question correctly. Is that clear?

Comment: You can compare `tag.text` with those strings and print only if it matches one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but I'll try to help.

```
soup.find_all('a', text=['revoked', 'active', 'default'])
```

This will select only those `<a …>` tags that have one of given strings as their text.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the snippet below in a similar occasion. See if this works with your goal:

```
table = soup.find(id="Table3")

for i in table.stripped_strings:
    print(i)
```

Comment: I tried your code and I am getting this error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"